# Linked List: How to Sort Doubly Linked List?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

This is the code for my doubly linked list. It works fine. I need help with sorting the data elements of this linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
int data;
struct Node* next;
struct Node* prev;
};
struct Node* head;//global variable

int GetNewNode(int x)
{
struct Node* newNode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
newNode->data=x;
newNode->prev=NULL;
newNode->next=NULL;
return newNode;
}

int InsertAtHead(int x)
{
struct Node* newNode =GetNewNode(x);
if(head==NULL)//list empty
{
    head=newNode;
    return;
}
head->prev=newNode;
newNode->next=head;
head=newNode;
}

void print()
{
struct Node* temp=head;//start printing from head
printf("Forward: ");
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    printf("%d ",temp->data);
    temp=temp->next;
}
    printf("\n");
}

   int main()
   {
   head=NULL;// initially taking it as null
   InsertAtHead(2);print();
   InsertAtHead(5);print();
   InsertAtHead(3);print();
   InsertAtHead(9);print();

   return 0;
   }
```

I want to sort the Data elements here.
I tried this:

```
void sort()
{
struct Node* temp=head;
int numTemp;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    if(temp->prev > temp->next)
    {
        numTemp=temp->next;
        temp->next= temp->prev;
        temp->prev=numTemp;
    }
}
}
```

But this compares the address, not the data of the linked list, How do i compare data and sort them accordingly ?

Comment: You *access* the data... `temp->prev->data` and such. Just don't dereference any NULL pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head`,`next` and `prec` in your `Node` struct are pointers and thus, they will just point to the respective node, in the same way as `temp`(in `sort()` function)is the pointer to the node you are currently accessing.

For accessing the `data` of node pointed by `temp`, you will do `temp->data`. Similarly, if you want to access the data of the next node(having address `temp->next`), you will do `temp->next->data`.

It seems, there is a problem with iterating through the linked list too.
To iterate forward in the linked list, you have to make `temp` point to the next node.

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    ...
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

This is how you can iterate through the list.

Comment: How to get temp to store data of the first node. Because for comparing i need to start from first node.

Comment: Can you please write the code for sort() function, in order to explain ur point.

Comment: @harsher Manan's answer is perfectly clear.  It's difficult to imagine any way in which it could be clearer or explained better.  Implementing it means a bit of editing to put that indirection in and then retest.  You should do that work.

Comment: @harsher Sorting is done in almost the same way as you would sort an array of numbers, there are various algorithms for that. Looking into them if you don't know how to.